# Is it possible to use continuous aggregate on timescaledb pre-built container

Tags: timescaledb

I am using `timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg14` image for development (production is on `timescale cloud`) and is trying to create a continuous aggregate of a hypertable, but got the error:

```
ERROR:  unrecognized parameter namespace "timescaledb"
SQL state: 22023
```

I have seen that this feature is only available on the `community` edition of timescale, so I am wondering if it is possible to use this feature in the pre-built container since they did not specify which license this pre-built container is.

Note:

- The image_id is `068da8e48541`, I pulled it around March 2022, so don't know the exact version.
- The timescale version is `2.5.2`
- postgresql version is `14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to `timescale/timescaledb:2.6.1-pg14` fixes the issue.